# How to limit the finds to unique values in an aggregate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Example dataset:

```
{
    "source": "http://adress.com/",
    "date": ISODate("2016-08-31T08:41:00.000Z"),
    "author": "Some Guy",
    "thread": NumberInt(115265),
    "commentID": NumberInt(2693454),
    "title": ["A", "title", "for", "a", "comment"],
    "comment": ["This", "is", "a", "comment", "with", "a", "duplicate"]
}
```

The dataset I'm using is basically a comment from a user, with a unique `commentID`. The comment itself is held as an array of words. I've managed to unwind the array, match the buzzword and get back all finds.

My problem now is getting rid of duplicates, where buzzwords show up several times in a comment. I suppose I have to use a group, but can't find a way to do it.

The current pipeline is:

```
[
    {"$unwind": "$comment"},
    {"$match": {"comment": buzzword } }
]
```

Which does work just fine. But if I'm searching for the buzzword "a", in the above example it will find the comment twice, as the word "a" shows up twice.

What I need is a JSON for the pipeline to drop all duplicates past the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a single pipeline without **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** that takes advantage of the array operators **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** and **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)**. The former will give you the first element in a given array and this array will be a result of filtering elements using the latter, **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)**.

Follow this example to get the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "comment": buzzword } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "source": 1,
            "date": 1,
            "author": 1,
            "thread": 1,
            "commentID": 1,
            "title": 1,
            "comment": 1,
            "distinct_matched_comment": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                    {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$comment",
                            "as": "word",
                            "cond": {
                                "$eq": ["$$word", buzzword]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

**Explanations**

In the above pipeline, the trick is to first filter the comment array by selecting just the elements which satisfy a given criteria. For example, to demonstrate this concept, run this pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "filtered_comment": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": ["This", "is", "a", "comment", "with", "a", "duplicate"], /* hardcoded input array for demo */
                    "as": "word", /* The variable name for the element in the input array. 
                                     The as expression accesses each element in the input array by this variable.*/
                    "cond": { /* this condition determines whether to include the element in the resulting array. */
                        "$eq": ["$$word", "a"] /* condition where the variable equals the buzzword "a" */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dbd747be80cdcab63703dc"),
    "filtered_comment" : [ 
        "a", 
        "a"
    ]
}
```

As the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)**'s `input` parameter accepts an expression that resolves to an array, you can use an array field instead.

---

Taking the result above further, we can show how the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operator works:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "distinct_matched_comment": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                    ["a", "a"], /* array produced by the above $filter expression */
                    0 /* the index position of the element we want to return, here being the first */
                ]   
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dbd747be80cdcab63703dc"),
    "distinct_matched_comment": "a"
}
```

Since the  expression in the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** operator

```
{ "$arrayElemAt": [ <array>, <idx> ] }
```

can be any valid expression as long as it resolves to an array, you can combine the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** expression from the beginning of this example as the array expression since it returns an array thus your final pipeline will look like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "distinct_matched_comment": {
                "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                    {  /* expression that produces an array with elements that match a condition */
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$comment",
                            "as": "word",
                            "cond": {
                                "$eq": ["$$word", buzzword]
                            }
                        }
                    },                  
                    0 /* the index position of the element we want to return, here being the first */
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This solution somehow returns all datasets for me.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you. Now I'll have to dig into HOW this works. :D

Comment: Nice answer with less overhead than mine +1

Comment: @DAXaholic Cheers!

Comment: @AndersBernard I've added some explanations with the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will make the next steps much easier.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be with `$group` like so

```
...
{ $unwind: "$comment"},
{ $match: {"comment": buzzword } },
{
    $group: {
        _id : "$_id",
        source: { $first: "$source" },
        date: { $first: "$date" },
        author: { $first: "$author" },
        thread: { $first: "$thread" },
        commentID: { $first: "$commentID" },
        title: { $first: "$title" }
    } 
}
...
```

Another way would be to use `$project` prior unwinding the array in order to get rid of the duplicate words like so

```
...
{
    $project: {             
        source: 1,
        date: 1,
        author: 1,
        thread: 1,
        commentID: 1,
        title: 1,
        comment: { $setUnion: ["$comment"] }
    }
},
{$unwind: "$comment"},
{$match: {"comment": buzzword } }
...
```

---

Update due to comment:

To retain the `comment` array you could project the array to another field and unwind that instead like so

```
...
{
    $project: {             
        source: 1,
        date: 1,
        author: 1,
        thread: 1,
        commentID: 1,
        title: 1,
        comment: 1,
        commentWord: { $setUnion: ["$comment"] }
    }
},
{$unwind: "$commentWord"},
{$match: {"commentWord": buzzword } }
...
```

[image: Pipeline execution]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed help. Is there a way to somehow retain the comment array? Else I'll have to look it up later.

Comment: ^^ Your updated solution keeps the comments, but somehow skips on removing the duplicates. Well, worst case I can remove duplicates in RStudio.

Thank you for that solution anyway, as it is simple and elegant enough for me to understand it despite my lack of knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean with skipping removing the duplicates exactly? The result won't give you the first document twice if you use "a" as buzzword but the comment array is the original comment array (with duplicates) - shouldn't be the latter one the original array?

Comment: Well, I had the pipeline run on my test buzzword:

6551 hits, out of which 4590 are unique.

So somehow it's not selecting for the unique when keeping the array intact.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible but without example it is hard to troubleshoot it

Comment: Rechecked my pipeline, and it's an exact copy of your solution. Still: duplicates aren't filtered out.

If anyone has an idea why, I'm really curious where I screwed up. :D

Thank you for your solution anyway DAXaholic. It's easy to understand and thus also a great help for a n00b like me.